# $G$ cannot have a subgroup $H $ with $|H| = n-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups

I'm trying to prove a group $G$ cannot have a subgroup $H$ with $|H| = n-1$ if $|G|=n > 2$. Here is my attempt:

The order of subgroup must divide the order of its group, and thus we would have $(n - 1) \mid n$. But if $n > 2$ then $n < k(n-1)$ for any $k>1$, contradiction. Is that correct?

Comment: I would say so.

Comment: Thank you @milore. I know it's not very elegant, but I suppose it will git-r-done.

Comment: Another way of writing the last part: $(n-1)|n$ implies $(n-1)|(n-(n-1))$, i.e. $(n-1)|1$, which is of course false when $n-1>1$.

Comment: @Hank Igoe, really I would say your proof is as elegant as it gets, it is the simplest thing you can think of, and simplicity makes up an important part of elegance.

Comment: Thank you very much @milore

Comment: Compare also your proof with the ones in [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591430/subgroup-of-order-n-1-of-a-group-of-order-n).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof using Lagrange's theorem works perfectly fine. In case you want a simpler proof, here is one.

Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of order $n-1$ and let $x\in G\setminus H$. Then, for any $h\in H$, you must have $xh\in G\setminus H$ since $x\notin H$. But this implies that $xh=x$ for any $h\in H$, which means that $H=\lbrace 0_{G} \rbrace$, the trivial subgroup. This is only possible if $n=2$ which concludes the proof.

Comment: I like that this comes from first-principles.  +1

Answer (score 1):

In general,  $(n,n-1)=1$.  That's $n$ and $n-1$ are coprime.   One way to see it is that $n-(n-1)=1$, so since a linear combination equals $1$, anything that divides both divides $1$.

Now by Lagrange this is ruled out for $n\gt2$. That's a group of order $n$ has no subgroup of order $n-1$.